# Norm infty how prove the definition

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

Show that $||A||_\infty$ norm of $ M $ canbe calculed as  $ ||A||_\infty = \max_{i={1,..,m}}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$.
Solution 
Let $y=Ax \Rightarrow y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}*y_j $

$||A||_\infty= \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac {  ||Ax||_\infty }{  ||x||_\infty }=\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac {\max_{1 <i <m } |(Ax)_i|}{||x||_\infty }< \sup_{x\neq 0}\max_{1 <i<m }\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac {|a_{ij}||x_j|}{|x_j|}=\max_{1 <i <m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$
This is correct ?
Help me please!

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix?

Comment: Yes, A is matrix

Comment: That is important information. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your argument is slightly off. Here's what I believe you were trying to do:
\begin{multline*}
\left\Vert A\right\Vert _{\infty}=\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \neq0}\frac{\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert }{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }=\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \neq0}\frac{\max_{i}\left|\sum_{j}a_{ij}x_{j}\right|}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }\leq\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \neq0}\frac{\max_{i}\sum_{j}\left|a_{ij}\right|\left\Vert x\right\Vert }{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }\\=\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert \neq0}\max_{i}\sum_{j}\left|a_{ij}\right|=\max_{i}\sum_{j}\left|a_{ij}\right|.
\end{multline*}
However, this only establishes 
$$
\left\Vert A\right\Vert _{\infty}\leq\max_{i}\sum_{j}\left|a_{ij}\right|.
$$
To arrive at the desired result, you'll need to establish the reverse
inequality. To do this, try to find a unit vector $x$ such that $\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert \geq\max_{i}\sum_{j}\left|a_{ij}\right|$.

Comment: Help me with a hint please for continue

Comment: I'm not sure how much I can say without giving the answer away. Pick an interesting 2x2 or 3x3 matrix and see if you can find a vector $x$ as I suggest. Generalize your findings.